# How to extract single record ( id ) from JSON response and display in DOM using VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I have created a List view to see records from a JSON API response. Now I     want user to click on a icon eg. '>' to see only that record on the full page ( Detail View ). I am not sure which vue directive I need to use and how to display in the DOM.

I tried this http://localhost:8000/Patients/1/?format=json but then directive v-for is not working

```
<template>
      <div id="app" class="container">
        <p v-if="loading">Loading...</p>
        <div v-else>
       <h3 class="heading" style="text-align:left">Patients List</h3>
      <input id="lens" v-model= "search" placeholder ="Search here">
      <br></br>



  </div>


      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="patient in filteredPatients" v-bind:key="patient">
            <td>{{ patient.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.first_name + " " + patient.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.mobile }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.email }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>




    </div>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      patients: '',
      search: '',

    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loading = true;
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8000/Patients/?format=json')
      .then(response => (this.patients = response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)

  },




computed: {
    filteredPatients() {
      return this.patients.filter(patient => {
       return `${patient.first_name} ${patient.last_name} ${patient.email}           ${patient.mobile} ${patient.id}`.includes(this.search);

    })
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Try to `console.log(response)` before you assign to patients. And make patients an empty array in your data `patients: []`

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov I am not seeing any error when I use http://localhost:8000/Patients/1/?format=json instead of http://localhost:8000/Patients/?format=json Just a blank page

Comment: What's the response look like (i.e., the contents of `response.data`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `filteredPatients()`method you are only returning three field i.e `first_name,last_name and email` but from your loop you are expecting to get five fields i.e `id,first_name,last_name,email and mobile`

How about you get your data directly from the patients value in the data section but you will first have to change it to an array.

After that have an `onclick` listener on the table rows and pass the specific product as an argument to the listener method.This way you will have the selected/clicked record.From here you can pass the record to the other page as props.

So the final code would look somehow like this:

```
      <div id="app" class="container">
        <p v-if="loading">Loading...</p>
        <div v-else>
       <h3 class="heading" style="text-align:left">Patients List</h3>
      <input id="lens" v-model= "search" placeholder ="Search here">
      <br></br>



  </div>


      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Mobile</th>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>


          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(patient,id )in  patients" :key="id" @click="getOneRecord(patient)">
            <td>{{ patient.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.first_name + " " + patient.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.mobile }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.email }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>




    </div>


  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      patients: {},
      search: '',

    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.loading = true;
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:8000/Patients/?format=json')
      .then(response => (this.patients = response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .finally(() => this.loading = false)

  },




computed: {
    filteredPatients() {
      return this.patients.filter(patient => {
       return `${patient.first_name} ${patient.last_name} ${patient.email}           ${patient.mobile} ${patient.id}`.includes(this.search);

    })
  },
methods:{
   getOneRecord(record):{

}

}
```